# RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, rsa

I'm getting the error on one server in a load-balanced application:

> Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'.
>   Error message from the provider: Not enough storage is available to
>   process this command.

I tried decrypting the web.config using `aspnet_regiis` on both servers.

The same server where the issue occurred is not allowing me to decrypt the file. The decryption attempt also throws the same error "Not enough storage is available to process this command.".

I've got tens of gigabytes of free space on both drives on the server. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

A server admin had copied the encrypted web.config from one server to another.

For this reason, the decryption would not work, even manually. After replacing it, it works fine.

The "insufficient storage" error message was misleading.